# Deploying a JAX-RS Java API Webapp on Azure API App Services

Tags: java, rest, api, azure, tomcat

So I'm trying to deploy a Java RESTful API app built using JAX-RS and Jersey. Specifically this example[1]. It is able to run locally on a Tomcat 8.5 server without any problems and it can be deployed as a Docker Container using the Eclipse Azure toolkit.

My issue arises when I try to follow this[2] guide to deploy the app using Azure's API App services. The paths that are working locally e.g. "localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/hello/mkyong" do not respond when deployed on Azure. e.g. when trying "apidemo.azurewebsites.net/RESTfulExample/rest/hello/mkyong" I get a 404 HTTP response where the description is "The requested resource is not available."

This is the web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
 <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-
 class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is the main java file

```
package com.mkyong.rest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {
    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
        String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

1. https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-java-api-app

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

And ensure you using jersey 2 and all jars needed are loaded in WEB-INF/lib on your war, also check for the name of the war, and if you working on eclipse check this: org.eclipse.wst.common.component property: context-root

Comment: "org.eclipse.wst.common.component property: context-root" What am I supposed to look for here? And do I create a new directory under WEB-INF where I put all my .jar files?

Comment: see on the property with name is "context-root" look on the value.There should be a directory called "lib" under WEB-INF.